# Keyboard shortcut to open Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript

On a Mac, I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut to open Google Chrome.  I know how to set a keyboard shortcut in the system preferences, however I'm unsure how to script it and hook it up.

Is this possible through AppleScript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to use any third party applications you need to create a service and assign it a shortcut.

Open Automator and select Service. You want it to look like the following :
[image]

Save it to its default location. ie `~/Library/Services`

Open System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Keyboard Shortcuts. Enable the service and assign it a shortcut.
[image]

Comment: Yo! You need to charge your battery! :D

Comment: I have to notice that this solution is slow (delay is ~0.5 sec) and works not from every application.

Answer (score 2):

Shortcuts for Automator services might not always work until the service has been selected once from the menu bar. And they won't be available in [applications that don't have a Services menu](https://superuser.com/questions/432969/services-keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work-for-some-mac-apps). There's usually also a noticable delay before they are run.

Using a third party application like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) or [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/) would probably be a better idea.

Another option would be [assign shortcuts to AppleScripts](https://superuser.com/a/264943/69039) like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with AppleScript alone -- there's no way to bind a keyboard shortcut to execute an arbitrary command.

Instead of writing something yourself, you may want to take a look at some existing launcher applications, like [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/), [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php), or [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'd prefer not to use a launcher application.

Comment: Then you're out of luck -- the Keyboard Shortcuts settings in System Preferences can only be used to rebind existing menu items and certain preset global commands, not to create new commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick.
Use Ctrl + ↑ to create a new desktop, say desktop2, and drag chrome application into that new desktop.

Open the keyboard preference pane, switch to the shortcut tab, and select  mission control to assign a key to that desktop2. Now you can switch to chrome use that key.

[image]